# How do I send a file to a batch file in Win XP?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm running Window XP and I have a java utility that accepts an input file as a param. I'd like to automate passing in the filename through windows, so I can select "Open With... -> batch file" and it runs the batch file using the file I seleted.

Here's my minify.bat file:

```
java -jar \\server\_yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar -v  \\server\JS_output\file_to_shrink.js

pause
```

**Here's the question:**
How can I replace "\server\JS_output\file_to_shrink.js" with a variable that accepts the input from "Open With" when I right click a file?

**UPDATE:**
Follo up question. Thanks to Martin, I now have this, which works great:

```
java -jar \\server\_yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar -v  %1
```

I'd like to provide another param to the java util for the output. So what I need is this:

How can I take %1 which contains **some_file.js** and create another variable from that which contains **some_file-min.js**? Essentially I want my java util command to be like this:

```
va -jar \\server\_yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar -v -o outputFileVar  %1
```

Comment: This may help: [How to Add Items to the "Send To" Menu in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310270)

Comment: If `%1` is `some_file.js`, then what you want is `%~dpn1-min.%~x1`. Take away the `dp` to lose the leading path. See `Help call` for details.

Comment: @bobbogo I replaced outputFileVar with %~dpn1-min.%~x1 and it worked like a charm. THANKS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a batch file (a text file ending with .bat)

In the file put the commandline you want with %1 as the name of file you will click on

Then just associate the extention with the .bat file in the normal way (open with -> browse )

Comment: They asked how to execute a batch file with the open with functionality

Comment: +1 It was very helpful. I do have another question though. I've included it up above.

Comment: @Jamis "open with" runs the command with the name of file you click on as the first (and only) argument. In a batch file the commandline arguments are inserted where you put %1, %2 etc

Comment: I just finaly updated the above to include my follow on question. How can I modify string %1 to change the output (see above).

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing exactly the same thing with YUI Compressor... but I wanted to have the batch process all of the files I sent it using the Send To shortcut, so I came up with this:

```
@ECHO off

GOTO minify

:minify
SET str=%1
SET str=%str:.js=.min.js%
SET str=%str:.css=.min.css%
java -jar "C:\Program Files\yuicompressor-2.4.2\build\yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar" %1 -o %str%
SHIFT
IF NOT "%~1"=="" GOTO minify
```

Comment: thank you. This is great. I tried using sendTo but ran into issues. I'll definitely give this a try.